# Chemical name of a solution of ions such as salt dissolved in water

Tags: water, salt

Is there any chemical name for the solutions of ions in water? I want to find out the name given to an aqueous solution of ions such as $\ce{Na+}$ and $\ce{Cl-}$ ions in water. Would it be something like aqueous solution of ions?

Comment: For your specific case, how about "brine".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific name but *some* authors may use the word aquated when they wish emphasize that the ion is surrounded by /weakly bound/coordinated to water. Google Scholar shows that about 10,000 documents use this term.

Examples:

Extreme case (i) aquated electron (ii) aquated $\ce{Na+}$ etc.

Comment: Aqueous electrolyte solution.